# Where do I find those WinForms controls?

Tags: winforms, controls

I am looking for a WinForms control that, I believe, in the days of VB 6.0 (I can't remember if it was VB 6 or .NET 1.1) used to be called the *ButtonImage* or *ImageButton* or some such. Whatever it was called is not important.

What it used to look like and behave like is the important thing.

If you open **Control Panel -> Add Remove Programs** in Windows XP, the buttons on the left **Change or Remove Programs**, **Add New Programs**, etc. use tat control. I want a control that looks like that. It's a button with an image but stays pressed when it is selected.

Secondly,  I am looking for a splitter. I see one in the Toolbox in Windows Forms apps, but when I try to change its size at runtime, it won't.

Do I have to use a *SplitterContainer* first or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may make use of RadioButton control or CheckBox control.

Add the control and change the **Appearance** property of RadioButton to Button. Add a BackgroundImage to that.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this control doesn't exist in Windows Forms. You will probably find one in commercial control libraries, look for Outlook-type menus.

For the splitter, you have to use a SplitterContainer, which is two panels separated by a splitter. Then you add your controls on both splitters and will be able to move the splitter and everything.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you can make the button use an image by tweaking the properties like so

```
Button1.Text = ""
Button1.Size = New Size(100, 100)
Button1.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageAboveText
Button1.Image = My.Resources.Image1
```

That would make the button look like this

[image]

You could also swap out the image every time the user clicks with the buttons click event.

Make sure to replace image1 and image2 with the real images.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Button1.Image = image1 Then
        Button1.Image = image2
    Else
        Button1.Image = image1
    End If
End Sub
```

You if you want the image to border and hover to be different try messing around with the `button.FlatStyle = flat` and the `FlatAppearance` property's.